# conditional redirect apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am setting up a webpage to host files for some users.  Right now if you go to the directory blah/folder you will be presented with apaches default folder view.  This folder view is ideal, however I would like to prevent people from going straight to the folders in the server directory.

Right now I have a login page which starts a session and if the users logs in correctly will direct them to their top directory and set a session variable.

I would like to have a way that whenever someone attempts to access a file or folder on my server, it checks for this variable and if it is not present it directs them back to the login page and if it is present shows them the default folder view.

I was thinking I could use .htaccess to redirect to a php file that checks the session status, but I don't know how I would keep this from running in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a members page that you want only to be accessed when a user is logged in and a login page that can be accessed by anyone.

You can use $_SESSION[ ] to do this

Create a header page that is included in both files and use session_start()

Login page should look something like this

```
 <?php
  require_once 'header.php';
  if(isset($_POST['user']&&$_POST['pass'])
  {
    //validate the values and check if user login credentials are right
   $_SESSION['loggedin']='true';
  }
 ?>
```

Members page should have something like this

```
<?php
 require_once 'header.php';
 if($_SESSION['loggedin']=='true')
 {
  echo'you can access this page member';
 }
 else{
 echo'Sending you back Mr';
 header('Location: http://somesite.com/login.php');
 }
?>
```

Comment: This looks like it is reasonable (can't test it at the moment because I'm on a computer core where I don't have write access to my session_path).  What I don't see is a way to have the server only run the file once, then fwd the authenticated user to the folder view (not sure how Apache makes the folder view).

Comment: Do you want the user to view all the files and folder that are in the root of apache ?

Comment: as an example.  If the user goes directly to website.com/User right now they will see apache's directory view.  I want to check for a session and confirm that the User has premission to see that directory.  If they do, they see the standard apache directory view, if not they are redirected to the login page.  I'm not sure how to execute a php file then show the apache directory view.

Comment: You would have to show the apache directory view inside the members php file. Use function like shell_exec( ) to execute ls command and store its output. Then for each output make a link and follow the same procedure.